# Activity.addContentView(View) == ViewGroup.addContentView(View)?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, window, viewgroup

I have a question regarding Android Activitys:

An Activity has the Method `addContentView(View)` while a ViewGroup has a (similar?) `addView(View)` Method.

Unfortunately its undocumented where the View from `addContentView` is placed. Is it like a `LinearLayout` just adding the View to the bottom, or is it more like a `FrameLayout`, which adds its Views "onTop" ? Does it depend on the `ViewGroup` set by `setContentView`?

If I dive into the sources I see that `addContentView` will call `Window`'s abstract Method `addContentView`. Unfortunately I cannot see which class is implementing this Method. So whats the behaviour of Activitys `addContentView` exactly?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The base layout of every activity is a `FrameLayout`. This means the layout you usually set via `setContentView()` is a child of this layout. `addContentView()` adds just another child, therefore it behaves like a `FrameLayout` *(which means it adds new UI elements above existing ones)*.

You can check this by using a tool called [`hierachyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) from your `ANDROID_SDK\tools` folder. Here are two screenshots:

[image]

*This is the layout before calling `addContentView()`, my activity consists of the default FrameLayout, holding a LinearLayout with a Button (my layout here). This is reflected in the bottom row here, the other elements above are the title/statusbar.*

[image]

*After adding a TextView via `addContentView()` it looks like this. You can see that the base FrameLayout got a new child.*

Comment: Wow. Really appreciate your answer, Thanks. your tip and the tool you suggested will save me a lot of hours! You are the kind of user that makes Stackoverflow so great!

Comment: hierarchiviewer is not deprecated but there is a option

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addContentView(View view,
              LayoutParams params) {
  mActivity.addContentView(view, params);
}
```

//

```
public static void SetActivityRoot(Activity c) {
      View v = ((ViewGroup)c.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
    
      ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(c);
      LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      sv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    
      ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    
      sv.addView((View) v);
      c.addContentView(sv, lp);
    }
```

//

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  LinearLayout mainLayout = 
    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
  
  //newButton added to the existing layout
  Button newButton = new Button(this);
  newButton.setText("Hello");
  mainLayout.addView(newButton);
  
  //anotherLayout and anotherButton added 
  //using addContentView()
  LinearLayout anotherLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  
  Button anotherButton = new Button(this);
  anotherButton.setText("I'm another button");
  anotherLayout.addView(anotherButton);
  
  addContentView(anotherLayout, linearLayoutParams);
 }

}
```