# Display different layout if the last item in ListView is deleted

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have the following code which is inside my Fragment to display all files in the folder in a listview. I also added the function to delete files from the listview. Once the last file is deleted I would like to display a different xml layout, which successfully works, if the tab is changed but not real time if the last item from the listview is deleted.

```
mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false ); //display if file exist
noFilesDisplayed = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nofile, container, false); //display if file doesn't exist
if (FilesInFolder != null) {
     mFrame3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //display the listview
     noFilesDisplayed.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide it
}
else {
     mFrame3.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide it
     noFilesDisplayed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //display if no file exist in the folder
}

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuSelect);
        String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
        String txt = ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).getText().toString();

        if (menuItemIndex == 0) {
            if (folder.exists()) {
                //File flEachFile = new File(folder.toString() + "/" + currentFileName + ".tp");
                flEachFile = new File(folder.toString() + "/" + txt + ".tp");
                flEachFile2 = new File(folder.toString() + "/." + txt + ".tp");
                if (flEachFile.exists()) {
                    flEachFile.delete();
                }
                if (flEachFile2.exists()) {
                    flEachFile2.delete();
                }
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dataList.setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed);
                //getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What's not happening is once the last item is deleted from the listview, the following command isn't changing the view: `dataList.setEmptyView (noFilesDisplayed);`
How do i achieve the view change once the last file is displayed? Maybe refresh the Tab view itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `setEmptyView()` is meant to only be called once when creating the `ListView`.

Set the `noFilesDisplayed` visibility to `GONE` and don't modify it manually, the `ListView`will do it for you. Maybe that'll solve the problem.

Also, [someone says here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807347/375929) that manually adding the inflated view to the ListView's parent (instead of providing the parent when calling `inflate()`) solved their similar problem.

Comment: If the last item is deleted I want to display `noFilesDisplayed` and hide the other layout

Comment: Other layout that is not all `ListView`? Well then do that manually, but let the `ListView` manage the empty view.

Comment: `mFrame3` holds the listview and `noFilesDisplayed` is a separate layout which displays if there is no item in the listview (folder is empty). How do I achieve it manually?

Comment: Is there something else in `mFrame3` besides the `ListView` that you want to hide? If there's not, you can just `setEmtpyView(noFilesDisplayed` and it all will work out without any additional effort. If there's something else - then use your logic 

`if (FilesInFolder != null) {
     mFrame3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //display the listview
}
else {
     mFrame3.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide it
}`

 but leave `noFilesDisplayed` alone - it will be managed automatically by `ListView` after you call `setEmptyView()`.

Comment: So take out `dataList.setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed)`? Just keep `setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed)`?

Comment: No, I meant dont do this: `noFilesDisplayed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. Because `ListView` already does that for you if you have set the view as it's empty view.

Comment: I have to do conditioning right? If (folder doesn't have have any file) { set visible();}

Comment: Yes, sure)

Oh, here's a question :) Does your list view display the files from the folder? Because if it displays something else, and you just want to hide or show the list based on your folder contents rather than the contents of the ListView, then I've been giving you wrong advice all along

Comment: Yes... The ListView displays the contents of a specific folder and when the last file from the folder is deleted I want to display the `noFilesDisplayed` layout instead of the `mFrame3` What would be the conditioning to check and display the proper layout?

Comment: No, you don't actually have to hide the `ListView`. Just use `setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed)` and when the list is emtpy - it will automatically show `noFilesDisplayed` instead of its contents when it's emtpy.

Comment: If i just enter `setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed)` it gives me this error: `The method setEmptyView(RelativeLayout) is undefined for the type OURTRIP` although I did inflate it beforehand as shown in the question.

Comment: `OURTRIP` is the main class which inflates the two xml layout

Comment: Well of course it doesn't have the method. `setEmptyView()` is a method of `ListView`, that's what it's telling you. Your right call is `dataList.setEmptyView(noFilesDisplayed);`