# How to pause the current activity when internet connection is not available in android app

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My android app requires internet connectivity. 
I have used broadcastreceiver to monitor the status of network connectivity. But, how do I pause the activity when the network connectivity goes off?

Comment: You can use ProgressDialog/AlertDialog to display a message like "Waiting for internet connection" that will wrap the whole view, also you  need to set dialog.setCancelable(false) so that it wont disappear when user click on screen

Answer (score 0):

If you get the status of the network connectivity, when it is not connected just call your Activity's onPause method?

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //pause anything else
}
```

then call onResume when you have network again?

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //resume application
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by pause the activity:

- If you want to prevent the user from doing anything on the activity when there is no internet then you should show a no network view and hide everything else
- If you want to actually trigger the on pause on that activity I think that can only happen when you move to another activity
- You can also finish the activity and show a toast message that you can't work without an internet connection

Please provide more clarification I might be able to help

- UPDATE:

Based on your comment, you can show a view with a retry button and hide the `ListView`

You can also make use of `ListView.setEmptyView(View)`, have a look at this StackOverflow post about that [setEmptyView on ListView not showing its view in a android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483508/setemptyview-on-listview-not-showing-its-view-in-a-android-app)

But I usually create something like that inside a `RelativeLayout`:

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutNoInternet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Please check your internet connection!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Retry"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`

I set the `visibility` of no internet layout to `gone` or `visible`

Comment: My application has two listview activities which gets populated based on the response from webservice. So, when there is no network connection, I would like to show a Toast message and hide everything else giving an option for the user to retry.