# emptyView always showing even if list is not empty

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-cursoradapter

I wish someone could take a look on that and let me know what is wrong.this is my emptyView container in the activity_main

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/display_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_shelter_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/empty_view_title_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_subtitle_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/empty_shelter_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/empty_view_sub_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#A2AAB0" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have set emptyView in each fragment, and even though when items are showing in the list it is still showing the empty view fields.

```
//set empty activity
    ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.display_view);
    View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    //create a new cursor adapter
    mCursorAdapter = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    listView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
```

I will highly appreciate it if you can tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: why sending `null`. You should pass `LIST`.

Comment: I'm working as per a previous app, second argument was being to set to null as well.

Comment: That code appears to be in `Fragment`, by you've said the layout is named `activity_main`. If this is the same code as in  [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50342800), then the problem is that you're using the same layout in both the `Activity` and the `Fragment`, and empty `View` in the `Activity` is never going to be hidden by the `ListView` in the `Fragment`. You want to use a separate layout for the `Fragment`, containing the `ListView` and empty `View`, and remove those from `activity_main`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483508/setemptyview-on-listview-not-showing-its-view-in-a-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hiding the empty_view in xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

my friends you have a send a null in adapter. send  a list

```
mCursorAdapter = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
```

and other way are used to check a listview is null hide  the 
display_view view and show the empty_view .