# Android: How to obtain an overlay on top of acitivity

Tags: android

when my application is installed for the first time by the user , i want to explain him what each activity does (like a quick tip) , it should look like the below picture

[image]

it should have the cancel button , and should not repeat after the first install,

I need suggestion or any useful links ,how to implement it, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with Preferences Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html

Comment: what about starting an `Activity` *(with no animation)* for the quick tip? so you can start it from anywhere with different tips every time?

Comment: @AdilSoomro i have 5 screens and i need 5 quick tips whenever the user uses that feature for first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SharePreference to store the state whether or not user have viewed your instruction. Just add a boolean value named as 'instructionViewed' to SharePreference. Every time your application launched, check the value. If true, don't show instruction. If false, show instruction. When user click the cancel button, set the value to true.

SharePreference is a very easy-using class to help store some information.You could google how use it.

Hope this helpful.

---

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.testpage);

         //Check SharePreference
         boolean instructionViewed = checkInstrunctionState();

         //If the instruction is not viewed, show instruction.    
         if(!instructionViewed){
               RelativeLayout yourLayout = createYourOwnUi();
               FrameLayout contentView  = (FrameLayout)(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
               FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,MATCH_PARENT);
               contentView.addView(yourLayout, lp);
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you..shared preference is perfect for this , iam confused about the UI, how can i get the exact same Ui as above pic.

Comment: yes how to implement that  the semitransparent black background, that transparent background thing is on top of the activity.

Comment: So your issue is how to add it to top of the activity.From my code, you could see that I added your instruction layout to a FrameLayout(id is android.R.id.content), we call it ContentView. ContentView is the top FrameLayout contains your application(It is added by Android).When you added your instruction layout to contentview, the instruction layout will on the top and it will cover your application.

Comment: Please read this thread. It explain more clearly.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979648/activity-addcontentviewview-viewgroup-addcontentviewview/9979929#9979929

Comment: Thanks for the link very useful..should i use createYourOwnUi(); in oncreate method of my activity?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please read. Yes, you should run createYourOwnUi in onCreate.

Comment: what goes under createYourOwnUi(); and where should i add my content?

Comment: Hi, I don't think I need post more things. Now your issue is how to create UI dynamically and you could google much thing about this.